# Excel Formula; Determine the current and expected value given different dates

Tags: excel

I have data in four Excel columns. Columns one and three have "dates" and the other two have values, but values in column three-four are reported earlier than those in column one-two. I need to be able to report the next date for which values will be available based on the day's date. So for today (5/5/2016), I would need to be able report the value for 2/29/2016, -0.1, and I also need to be able to show the next expected value on 5/13/2016, 0.2.

Can I do this using a formula in Excel? Thanks.

[image: [EThaE.png1]:]

```
12/31/2015  0       20160212    0.1
1/31/2016   -0.1    20160315    0
2/29/2016   -0.1    20160413    -0.1
3/31/2016   #N/A    20160513    0.2
4/30/2016   #N/A    20160614    #N/A
```

There are in four equal columns. Columns one and three are dates, although the date in column three is non-standard.

Comment: Help us help you, post some data in the Original Post to show exactly what you want.

Comment: Just an FYI there are many many ways to get what you want, but it all depends on how your data is structured.  A sample of your data would help narrow what we can do for you.  As it is this question is too broad and risks being closed as such.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this site. If I try to post data from Excel, it shows up all garbled together.

Comment: Just post it and someone will format it properly.

Comment: Post it in the original post not in the comment.  Use the edit link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will get it from Columns A and B:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(($A$1:$A$5=AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$A$5/((ISNUMBER($B$1:$B$5))),1)),),0))
```

Change the `A`a to `C`s and the `B`s to `D`s for the next formula.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ectrimm did it work for you?  If so please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.